# Few records in some tables are getting rejected (while running the import) after changing the Oracle database character-set to UTF-8 (AL32UTF8)

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, oracle10g

Few records in some tables are getting rejected (while running the import) after changing the Oracle database character-set to UTF-8 (AL32UTF8)

The character set was changed to UTF-8 and then the same data dump was re-loaded to ensure that Arabic language characters can be supported.

The error thrown by the Import log is as show below:

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "DATABASE"."TABLE"."ATTRIBUTE"
>   (actual: 73, maximum: 64)

Comment: Is your column byte or char semantic? If it's byte semantic then don't forget that UTF-8 is a multi-byte character set, which means that what would previously have been `varchar2(1)` would now have to be quadrupled.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's comment is most likely correct. If you originally had a string of 60 characters, it required 60 bytes of space in the single-byte encoding and would fit an a VARCHAR2(64).

With the multi-byte encoding UTF-8 the same string now uses 73 bytes and won't fit into a VARCHAR2(64) because the default unit for the VARCHAR2 declaration is bytes, not characters.

You will need to change all character columns from:

```
VARCHAR2(64)
```

to:

```
VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)
```

I strongly recommend not to use any length declarations in bytes because for validation it's almost impossible to predict if the string will fit or not. As an exmaple, it's easy to define an HTML text field that will limit an entry to 40 characters because it has an attribute for this very purpose. But it's very hard to create the same to limit the entry to 40 bytes measured in UTF-8 encoding. And how would you want to communicate it to the user anyway? (*You may not enter a name longer than 40 bytes when measured in UTF-8 encoding.*)